# Can't unsubscribe from realtime updates: Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some trouble unsubscribing from updates using Firestore's `onSnapshot` method.

I do some processing on a file with an external worker. It updates the Firestore database when it's finished. I listen for these updates on my front end using this code:

```
import store from "../store";
import db from "./firebase"
import { updateModelConversionProgress } from "../actions/updateModelConversionProgress";

const listenForConversions = (resource, id) => {
  const modelRef = db.collection(resource).doc(id);
  const unsubscribe = db.collection(resource).doc(id).onSnapshot(() => {});
  modelRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
    const model = doc.data();
    if (model) {
      store.dispatch(
        updateModelConversionProgress(
          id,
          model.file.uniqueFilename,
          model.conversionStatus
        )
      );
    }
    if (model && model.conversionStatus === "completed") {
      // Unsubscribe from updates
      unsubscribe();
    }
  });
};

export default listenForConversions;
```

This all works great, my UI updates when the database is updated. However, if I go to delete this file I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that the document has been deleted and thus the user doesn't have access to it anymore (I have security rules that only allow users to access documents that have their userID) hence the `Missing or insufficient permissions part`. Regardless, the UI should no longer be listening for updates, which makes me wonder why I'm getting this error message? I've tried passing an empty callback using the same document reference (i.e. `const unsubscribe = modelRef.onSnapshot(() => {});`) but then I just get the error message twice. The [documentation implies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) that I should use a different document reference anyway. I'm pretty sure I'm not unsubscribing properly, but I'm not sure what to change. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is intended. You are only able to view data if it is explicitly permitted. Since there is no data to execute the rules on, the permission is **not** explicitly given therefore the error.

If you don't want to see the error hit the console or bubble up, you can always pass an [`onError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onSnapshot) function that handles that specific error.

Comment: I understand the cause of this specific error, but I'm trying to unsubscribe from listening to changes to this specific document. The presence of the error seems to indicate I'm still subscribed it and thus when it is deleted the `onSnapshot` method is called (which it shouldn't be because I unsubscribed).

Comment: @quicklikerabbit When the error is thrown, you are not subscribed anymore since you don't have access. Essentially it auto-unsubscribes you.

Comment: I see. That does make sense as I only get the error message on delete. Still interesting that the `onSnaphsot` method is called even though I've unsubscribed.